# All-pairs table vs orthogonal array

Tags: techniques, pairwise-testing

After researching the web, I haven't found a clear explanation and example of the difference between `All-pairs table` and `orthogonal array`.

Can someone provide one?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this post and associated links over on Stack Overflow give a pretty comprehensive treatment on those and other techniques - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595283/orthogonal-and-combinatorial-testing-techniques